# "Log into Wifi" with Ad-Hoc WLAN with local HTTP

Tags: http, wifi, android-wifi

we run a little "router" device (~ raspberry pi) that provides an ad-hoc wifi (free / unsecured).
On the same device, there is a webservice with login page. All unauthenticated calls are reditected to that login page.

Somehow, all devices now believe that this is a wifi-login page.
(Androud, Windows and MAC) are asking the user to log into the Wifi (similarly as you do for free wifi in malls etc.).

The ad-hoc wifi is not online, so all the connectivity checks do not work:

- Apple iOS and macOS: captive.apple.com
- Microsoft Windows: [www.msftncsi.com/ncsi.txt](http://www.msftncsi.com/ncsi.txt)
- Google Android and Chrome: google.com/generate_204

The domains of that probe are not served by our service. yet, we see Devices try to access our local HTTP service and do these checks.

Comment: You've made a setup that looks like (for all intents and purposes, _is_) an open WiFi hotspot. You're seeing people and devices trying to connect to it like it is one. What's the question, exactly?

Comment: there is no login for the wifi required. you should only log into the WebApp if you decide to go there via browser

Comment: also, i get this annoying "log into wifi" notification on all OS, which i would also not like to appear (because it is missleading)